# SEAM projects run in JBoss AS?

Tags: java, jboss, seam

How do I run Seam applications in JBoss AS?

I put JBoss SEAM as a dependence (using MAVEN2) of my project and deployed it in JBoss AS - just that will sufice to make my project work properly (with all the features provided by JBoss Seam) or do I need to modify JBoss AS in any way (like, for example, include some extra seam library in the lib directory of JBoss AS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to modify your JBoss AS installation, deploying the SEAM JARs as part of your application EAR should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

option 20 and follow steps, you should have a good start up pom.xml.